# MySQL column = 0 returns true

Tags: mysql, sql

TL/DR:
I run this query = `"Select * from test where id = 0"` and it returns all the rows.

Here is my code below:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
   `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `desc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `desc`) VALUES
 ('AA', 'AA Desc'),
 ('BB', 'BB Desc');

  SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE id = 0
```

In my mind it should return no rows however it returns all the rows in the table. Am I missing something? Any help and explanation would be most welcome.

Comment: count will always return number of rows. since there is no id of `1`, it outputs `0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're performing an arithmetic comparison on a text field. MySQL will coerce the values in your ID column to a numeric value and compare it with zero. `AA`, when coerced, equals zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE id = '0'
```

You need to compare with a string, because comparing with a number will convert the table data to a number, and non-numeric strings convert to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have used datatype varchar, and inserted records like `AA`, `BB`

`SELECT count(*) FROM test WHERE id = '0'`

Comment: He's trying to get `0` as the count, this will return 1.

Answer (score -1):

You are giving `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL, as string in Table and Checking as number.
You Should check `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE id = '0'` if id is varchar(20) and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE id = 0` When id is int